# Is calling multiple APIs from a mobile app harmful?

Tags: android, api, sails.js, frontend, backend

I am developing an Android app with [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/#!/) backend. Assume that I have 3 different APIs, namely A, B and C. These APIs only fetch data return them with minor / no computations or update values in the databases. Each of these APIs take 300-400ms respectively on live.

Currently, I am running on a micro EC2 instance of Amazon Linux, which will be scaled as more users come in.

Is it a good idea calling 3 APIs from the Android app or having a single APIs which performs the job of all 3 APIs in a single call? My idea of creating 3 different APIs is to reuse the same in my [AngularJs](https://angularjs.org/) front end.

Comment: use IntentService or seperate thread to do this...But dont touch the main ui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good idea in terms of reusability as you're already using these APIs. But I would still go with an API that summs up the functionality of three calls with one just because mobile device don't always got a good internet connection. Using a single API call requires less traffic and decreases the loading and response time.
I would recommend measuring the API call time with the android emulator using extreme connection settings (EDGE, high latency) and compare the results.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use thread for each api, In android we use handler in the form of thread .You can run the api,s one by one by using handler.

Comment: It's also difficult to really understand "what is the OP's use-case," given the rather-scant description.  One wonders what the "three API's, A, B, and C," actually *do.*  Are they "three ways to do the same thing," or are they "three necessary parts of getting the job done?"  One wonders.

Comment: @MikeRobinson i think he is only assuming the api .these can be login ,register or any other ..

Comment: Could be.  Would get much better answers if the OP was edited to say more.  (Also possibly very-relevant is:  *"how many* users come in?")  Without concrete details, it's a shot in the dark.

Comment: Each of the 3 APIs are are different. I have updated the question. I want to know whether it will be a burden on the Android side of development.